# UWP Pivot maximum number of elements in header

Tags: xaml, uwp, pivot

I can I make my Pivot show a maximum number of elements in the header? For example, 5 elements.

I would like headers show like this:

[image]

As you can see, it shows only 5 elements. Also, headers are placed at the bottom of the `Pivot`.

Comment: Why don't you use `ListView` and change the `Frame` on selection changed?

Comment: Your screenshot looks like you want to implement a paging control. 
Is that right?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Yes! I though Pivot could be a good candidate. I currently have the ItemSource of the Pivot pointing to a list of PageViewModels that load the data on demand (when the view is loaded). Paging controls usually deal with indexes, that is something I don't wont.

Comment: Telerik UI for UWP has an existing paging control: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radpagination/overview It's open source project, you could think about using it.